# How does a Web Application like Google Hangouts get Client Side Information?

Tags: security, web-applications

Google Hangouts Web Application has a screen sharing feature and it allows user to select a particular application by providing a list of all applications running in the client machine.

Could somebody explain how this is accomplished? As per my understanding, this cannot be implemented in a typical web application due to security reasons.

Comment: I think it's done by the Chrome extension, not the web app itself.

Comment: @EduardoYáñezParareda - I don't have the Extension installed.